# PCB routing - Which of these would be a better design?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-layers

Case 1:
The route seems to be long!
[image]

Case 2: Two branches emerging out of a single via?
[image]

Comment: Downvote for lack of context - for a start, what signal is this trace carrying?

Answer (score 1):

It depends:

1. if you need to minimalize the voltage drop (high current circuits), the solution 2 seems better.
2. if signal propagation time is critical (high speed digital circuits), the solution 2 seems better too.
3. if impedance matching is critical (high frequency circuits), the solution 1 will be (probably) better.
4. if you need to minimalize the parasitic capacitance, the solution 2 seems better.
5. .....

So, you must make decision taking all in your head.